# Separate groups of ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview

I am trying to create an activity with 3 separate `ExpandableListView` with a `TextView` above the last one.
Because the 3rd list didn't work properly when all the lists were in the same view, I have placed the first two lists inside a header. But now the first two lists inside the header do not expand anymore.

Is there a way to have different `ExpandableListView` separated by static elements like a `TextView`? And can `ExpandableListView` work within a header?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you got to place them in the LinearLayout and dont forget to set measure specs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you mean by measure specs?

Comment: Do you mean set the size of the expandable lists? I can only do that for the first 2 but the last one is dynamic so it varies in size.

Comment: Measure specs tells listView how much space could it take.

Comment: You can override this in your own class that extends ExpandableListView